Why is there a factor of $i$ in the RNS action in Blumenhagen, Lüst & Theisen?
Blumenhagen Lüst and Theisen use the following real representation for the two-dimensional gamma matrices:
\begin{equation}
\rho^0 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 && 1\\
-1 && 0
\end{pmatrix}, \hspace{1cm}
\rho^1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 && 1\\
1 && 0
\end{pmatrix},\tag{7.74}
\end{equation}
and define Dirac conjugation as $\bar{\psi} = \psi^\dagger \rho^0$. Their form of the superconformal gauge RNS action in Minkowski space is
\begin{equation}
S = -\frac{1}{4 \pi} \int d^2 \sigma \Big( \frac{1}{\alpha^\prime} \partial^\alpha X^\mu \partial_\alpha X_\mu + i \bar{\psi}^\mu\rho^\alpha \partial_\alpha \psi_\mu \Big).\tag{7.24}
\end{equation}
The $\psi^\mu$ are Majorana spinors (which are real if the gamma matrices are real). If both the spinors and the gamma matrices are real, why is there a factor of $i$ in front of the fermion kinetic term? Is the book wrong?

They are anti-commuting objects.

@Prahar I know. How is that related to the factor of $i$?

Action is supposed to be real, right? What is the complex conjugate of the second term?

Thank you @Prahar, I had forgotten that the complex conjugate of a Grassmann product is usually defined with the order-swapping one would expect from taking the hermitian conjugate of operators. If anybody happens to run into the same problem, I recommend looking at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204489/grassmann-variables-and-complex-conjugate and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529496/is-the-fermion-mass-lagrangian-term-imaginary-instead-of-real.
