# Incompatible equations of motion in non-Hermitian (PT-symmetric) model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

There is an interesting paper on Goldstone theorem of non-Hermitian QFT.    arXiv:1808.00437.

On page page 8-9 equation (36)-(38), author says that having equations of motion that are NOT complex conjugate to each other is a potential problem.

What are the "potential problems?". Why are we not allowed to have equations of motions that are not complex conjugate to each other?

Thank you

Comment: presumably useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/311870/84967

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Once again, thank you for the helpful input.